# ¿Como puedo mostrar las reservaciones que hace un usuario logeado?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un sistema de reservaciones de mesa de un restaurante, lo que sucede es que la persona que quiera reservar una mesa debera registrarse y luego logearse para que pueda reservar hasta ese punto todo bien pero no se como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda ver sus reservas, teniendo en cuentra que hay una tabla de clientes y otra de reservas que se conecta con el id_cliente:

Esta es la tabla de clientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la de reservas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la variable que cree para el $_session:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es donde no se como podria llamar los datos de las reservaciones del usuario logeado, agradeceria mucho alguna ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No se si estas usando $_SESSION['usuario'] para guardar un true/false pero podrias guardar el id del cliete y usarlo para consultar a la base, si no podes usar esa variable podes declarar otra y llenarla durante el login con el id de usuario del estilo $_SESSION['usuario_id'].

Saludos